# Existence of integral manifold for a given distribution.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

The question is as follows:

In $M = \mathbb{R}^3$, for the distribution $D = \left<X1,X2\right>$ generated by the vector fields:
$$X_1 =  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + z^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, ~~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ 
 X_2 =  \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + z^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial z}$$
and such that every vector field $X \in \varkappa(D)$ (The set of vector fields tangent
to $D$) is a linear combination $aX_1 +bX_2$, where the
smooth functions $a = a(x, y)$ and $b = b(x, y)$ are uniquely determined.

Show that the only points
through which there exist integral manifolds are the points in the plane $z = 0$.

$\textbf{Some effort:}$

We know that the integral curves of
$X_1$ are $(x_0+t , y_0 e^{t^2}, z_0)$ and those of $X_2$ are $(x_0  , y_0 + t, z_0 e^{t^2})$. So that the respective local flows are $$\varphi_t(x,y,z) = (x + t , y e^{t^2}, z), ~~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ \psi_s(x,y,z) =(x  , y + s , z  e^{s^2}) $$
And the map
$$(s,t) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto (\psi_s \circ \varphi_t)(x_0, y_0 , z_0) = \psi_s (x_0 + t , y_0 e^{t^2}, z_0)= (x_0 + t  , y_0 e^{t^2} + s , z_0  e^{s^2})$$
will be  the integral surface through $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$.

After this I do not know what to do?!

Can someone help me in getting to to result?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know about [Frobenius' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(differential_topology))?

Comment: @Danu Thanks! How can we use Frobenius theorem for this question? How can we use involutivity of the distribution for to see the result?

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this with the Frobenius theorem, but otherwise you can check directly that the surface you define $\varphi: (s,t) \mapsto (x_{0} + t, y_{0}e^{t^{2}} + s, z_{0}e^{s^{2}})$ is an integral surface only when $z_{0}$ vanishes. The tangent space to this surface in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is spanned by the vectors

\begin{align*}
&\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t} = (1, 2ty_{0}e^{t^{2}}, 0),\\
&\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial s} = (0, 1, 2sz_{0}e^{s^{2}}).
\end{align*}

Then you can show that $X_{2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} + z^{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = (0, 1, z_{0}^{2}e^{2s^{2}}) \in \left\langle \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t}, \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial s} \right\rangle$ if and only if $z_{0} = 0$ (and similarly for the other vector field $X_{1}$). You can and should verify this by direct calculation.

Comment: Many thanks! How can we use Frobenius theorem for this question?

Comment: The Frobenius theorem gives conditions for when there exists an integral manifold tangent to your distribution. It happens precisely when the Lie bracket $[X_{1}, X_{2}]$ belongs to your distribution $D$, so you can compute the Lie bracket directly to see whether or not you have integral manifolds.

Comment: Many thanks! I found it. We have $[X_1 , X_2] = -2z^3 \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$. For this to be in our distribution $D$, we should have $z=0$. Am I right?

Comment: I haven't checked your computation but that sounds right :)